# COMO PUEDO CONCATENAR ESTAS LISTAS?

Tags: python, concat

Obtengo un error en la concatenación, me dice que no puedo concatenar esto. Me aparece un error en strategy, he intentado borrar el join e axis, pero sigue dando error.
El error es el siguiente: `TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'dict'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid`

```py
close_price = tsla['Close']
st = tsla['st']
st_signal = pd.DataFrame(st_signal).rename(columns = {0:'st_signal'}).set_index(tsla.index)
position = pd.DataFrame(position).rename(columns = {0:'st_position'}).set_index(tsla.index)

frames = [close_price, st, st_signal, position]
strategy = pd.concat(frames, join = 'inner', axis = 1)

strategy.head()
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Una de las primeras cosas que debes aprender como programador/a es que "me da un error" o "me dice que no puedo" no es muy útil para ayudarte a resolver el problema. Es mucho más útil que pegues en la pregunta (preferiblemente como texto y no como imagen) el mensaje de error completo que te sale.

Comment: A juzgar por el error, alguna de las variables `close_price`, `st`, `st_signal` o `position` contiene un diccionario. A la vista del código en cambio no parece que sea así. Prueba a hacer un `print(type(variable))` para cada una de esas, a ver si encuentras cuál es la que contiene un diccionario.

Answer (score 1):

Parece ser que tu error se debe a que estas intentando concatenar un diccionario, una opción es que aquello que intentas concatenar lo conviertas previamente a lista con `list()`, también puedes usar el método`append()`para ir añadiendo elementos a la lista o incluso utilizando el símbolo + que te permite concatenar dos listas diferentes. No obstante, no sé si es por ausencia de código pero me cuesta entender lo que ocurre.